# Screen dims and requires extra back button press after returning from PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android

I've added a simple PreferenceActivity to my app, accessible through a context menu button. I can access the PreferenceActivity fine, and everything there works. The issue is when you leave the PreferenceActivity via the back button. The app's main activity reappears, but then the entire screen dims down, almost like there is a dialog that popped up or the context menu never disappeared, but there isn't. You cannot interact with the ListActivity that is in the background without pressing the back button or menu button.

Anybody have any ideas as to why this would happen?

Main Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // get the inflater
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // inflate
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection;
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.refresh:
        refresh();
        return true;
    case R.id.subreddits:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

PreferenceActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.subreddit_preferences);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't write the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` that way. Instead of calling `super` first and then returning `true`, return the results of the chain to the superclass.

If that does not help, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Simple) that uses a `PreferenceActivity` and does not suffer from the problems you cite. See if you can deduce where your code differs from what I have.

Comment: Hm. I made that change (good call, thanks), but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @Chris: Try my sample. Once you have confirmed it does not exhibit the behavior you are encountering, start trying to figure out where my code and yours differ.

Comment: Interesting...so I tried adding my menu objects on the fly like you did, rather than inflating my xml, and that seemed to fix the problem. I don't mind adding them on the fly, but would like to figure out if I'm doing something wrong in my xml (I've added it to the original post).

Comment: In going through this, I found the problem. Ignore that last comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris what was the problem?? I'm having the same issue!

Comment: @Chris never mind, fixed my problem (and documented it in an answer!)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and my problem was that I had put a sub-menu under my "Settings" menu item.

Removing it fixed the issue.